# Table with column widths that exceed the container width

Tags: html, css, html-table

When I put a table within a fixed-width container and the sum of the widths of the columns exceeds the container width, as a general rule, I observe the table won't overflow the container, but the columns will be rendered narrower than their styled width.

But I also observed some cases where the table indeed does overflow. One case that especially puzzles me is shown here (or in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky2okqy5/5/)):

```
    <div style="width:750px;border:1px solid black">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input style="width: 210px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 200px"></td>
                        <td><input style="width: 200px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width:400px">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In Chrome (40.0), the column widths are preserved and the table overflows. In IE and FF, the table fits the container and the columns are shortened. 
Is there a general rule for "squeezing" tables into containers? Is Chrome is buggy? Or is such convoluted table design hoplessly beyond specification?

Comment: what you want to happen is?

Comment: you are setting widths after widths for everything.. why would that be a chrome bug

Comment: Table layout is not that rigidly specified, there is some freedom for browsers to chose how to render in different situation. Formatting your table using `table-layout:fixed` can often help to get some more control over how stuff is rendered, especially when table cells have given widths.

Comment: My actual use case is a webapp with dozens of different tables that have various predefined elements in them. Their width is given by their style classes and they don't always match the table's width (given by the fixed container). However, in IE, it all fits smoothly. I'd like to get the same result in Chrome.

Comment: You are looking at div borders and getting confused. The table is still wider than view port.

Answer (score 0):

You can set those width of the input to `max-width:100%` and `width:100%` 
take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ky2okqy5/6/

UPDATED https://jsfiddle.net/ky2okqy5/7/

Comment: Your version doesn't overflow, but the columns (and the entire table) become much shorter. What I'd like to achieve is having columns that take up as much space as possible (the way my example is displayed in IE and FF).

Comment: This looks now (almost) the same in IE and Chrome, but the empty <td> element (the one styled with max-width: 300px in your example) is squashed to 4px. And when I add width:100% to it, the cell next to it gets squashed.